# How do I include exception handling?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-applications, visual-studio-2012

I'm creating a web form that takes user input for certain things and displays it after hitting Ok...but I don't have any way to check if the input is valid. VB is new to me and I would imagine "if" statements would work...but they don't seem like they do.

```
Public Class HelloForm
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub cmdOk_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdOk.Click
        msgLabel.Text = nameTextBox.Text + ", " + lastTextBox.Text + "; " + addrTextBox.Text + ", " +
                        cityTextBox.Text + ", " + stateTextBox.Text + ", " + zipTextBox.Text + "; " +
                        phoneTextBox.Text



    End Sub
End Class
```

When I run this, everything works. But say if I include an invalid phone number or zip code (something). How and where do I include exception handling to do this?

If I put in "asdhasd" into the Phone Number input, I want it to say "Invalid Phone Number".

(I guess I probably should include a button that clears all output/input as well. ;x)

Comment: You don't want exception handling. You want validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is to drag some RequiredFieldValidator's and Regular ExpressionValidator's onto your page they're best used to validate input...

Drag them beside your texboxes..

An example for your phone number textbox would be:

```
   <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2"
    ControlToValidate="phoneTextBox" ErrorMessage="Numbers only" 
    runat="server"  ValidationExpression="^[0-9]+$" Display="Dynamic">
   </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

To make your phone textbox a required field:

```
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
      ErrorMessage="*Please enter phone number"
      ControlToValidate="phoneTextBox" Display="Dynamic">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

To make your name textbox have chars only:

```
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ControlToValidate="nameTextBox"
        ErrorMessage="Letters only" runat="server" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z]+$" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

You can copy and paste the above onto your page.

Comment: how can i tie them together with the fields?
where do i drag them? onto the fields or beside them? how can i modify it to know what is valid and what is not

Comment: I see. Would the validation expression for letters only be "^[a-ZA-Z]?
And where to I go to edit these?

Comment: It is giving me an "End of Statement expected" message in the code behind and says "RegularExpressionValidator is a type and cannot be used as an expression"

Also "Identifier expected" in the last line's "/" in </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

And it says where it says "ID": "Method arguements must be enclosed in partentheses"

Comment: Where are you putting the RegularExpressionValidator ?

Comment: In the properties of that tool?

Comment: click on the "source" tab at the bottom of the HelloForm.aspx page and paste what I've put in there..

Comment: Thanks! 
So all that should check if the field is valid or even filled (requiredvalidator) when I run it?